# spark: read parquet file and process it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I am new of Spark 1.6. I'd like read an parquet file and process it.
For simplify suppose to have a parquet with this structure:

```
id, amount, label
```

and I have 3 rule:

```
amount < 10000 => label=LOW
10000 < amount < 100000 => label=MEDIUM
amount > 1000000 => label = HIGH
```

How can do it in spark and scala?

I try something like that:

```
case class SampleModels(
  id: String,
  amount: Double,
  label: String,
)

val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/path/file/")
val ds = df.as[SampleModels].map( row=>
    MY LOGIC 
    WRITE OUTPUT IN PARQUET
)
```

Is it right approach? Is it efficient? "MYLOGIC" could be more complex.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the right way to work with spark. If your logic is simple, you can try to use built-in functions to operate on dataframe directly (like [when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#when(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.Object)) in your case), it will be a little faster than mapping rows to to case class and executing code in jvm and you will be able to save the results back to parquet easily.

Comment: This is the right answer. In general, prefer to use the spark dataframe/dataset operations. The operations are passed to Spark SQL's [Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html), an optimization engine that runs under-the-hood to better perform your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct approach.
It will do one pass over your complete data to build the extra column you need.

If you want a sql way, this is the way to go,

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/path/file/")
df.registerTempTable("MY_TABLE")
val df2 = sqlContext.sql("select *, case when amount < 10000 then LOW else HIGH end as label from MY_TABLE")
```

Remember to use hiveContext instead of sparkContext though.